# showing uploaded image within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

- When I upload the image can you tell me how to show image within the red box
- Providing code below

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWXmpd

```
<div class="upload-image">
    <div class="upload-image-preview"></div>
    <input type="file" name="file" value="Upload Image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using following jQuery.

```
$("input[name=file]").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var img = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.upload-image-preview').html(img);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Use following `CSS` to keep image size same as the preview div.

```
.upload-image-preview img{
    width: 100%;
    height:  100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPBQxX)**

Comment: hey what does new FileReader() does??

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like this to display your image before upload.

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var image, file;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
    src = this.src;
        $('#uploadPreview').html('<img src="'+ src +'"></div>');
    e.preventDefault();
   }
        };
        image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

```css
#uploadPreview {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#uploadPreview img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<div id="uploadPreview">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the image you can return the path of image.
And by js you can show that image on upload response via ajax call.